# How can i fix this return error in the .lua code?

Tags: lua

```
local QBCore = exports[Config.Utility.CoreName]:GetCoreObject()

function Notify(msg, type)
    if type == "primary" then 
        QBCore.Functions.Notify(msg, "primary")
    end
    if type == "success" then
        QBCore.Functions.Notify(msg, "success")
    end
    if type == "error" then
        QBCore.Functions.Notify(msg, "error")
    end
end

function Email(plateVeh,modelName,expire)
    if Config.Utility.Phone == "qb-phone" then
        TriggerServerEvent("qb-phone:server:sendNewMail", {
            sender = Language["Sender"],
            subject = Language["Subject"],
            message = Language["Email_1"]..plateVeh..Language["Email_2"]..modelName..Language["Email_3"]..expire,
        })
    elseif Config.Utility.Phone == "qs-smartphone" then
        TriggerServerEvent("qs-smartphone:server:sendNewMail", {
            sender = Language["Sender"],
            subject = Language["Subject"],
            message = Language["Email_1"]..plateVeh..Language["Email_2"]..modelName..Language["Email_3"]..expire,
        })
    elseif Config.Utility.Phone == "gksphone" then
        TriggerServerEvent("gksphone:NewMail", {
            sender = Language["Sender"],
            image = '/html/static/img/icons/mail.png',
            subject = Language["Subject"],
            message = Language["Email_1"]..plateVeh..Language["Email_2"]..modelName..Language["Email_3"]..expire,
        })
    elseif Config.Utility.Phone == "roadphone" then
        TriggerServerEvent("roadphone:receiveMail", {
            sender = Language["Sender"],
            image = '/public/html/static/img/icons/app/mail.png',
            subject = Language["Subject"],
            message = Language["Email_1"]..plateVeh..Language["Email_2"]..modelName..Language["Email_3"]..expire,
        })
    elseif Config.Utility.Phone == "d-phone" then
        TriggerServerEvent("mail:functions:sendmail:tosource", 1, Language["Sender"], Language["Sender"], Language["Subject"], Language["Email_1"]..plateVeh..Language["Email_2"]..modelName..Language["Email_3"]..expire, nil)
    elseif Config.Utility.Phone == "renewed-phone" then
        TriggerServerEvent("qb-phone:server:sendNewMail", {
            sender = Language["Sender"],
            subject = Language["Subject"],
            message = Language["Email_1"]..plateVeh..Language["Email_2"]..modelName..Language["Email_3"]..expire,
            button = {
                buttonEvent = "Renewed-Debt:server:AcceptShit",
                buttonData = 10,
                isServer = false
            }
        })
    elseif Config.Utility.Phone == "road-phone" then
        TriggerServerEvent('roadphone:receiveMail', {
            sender = Language["Sender"],
            subject = Language["Subject"],
            message = Language["Email_1"]..plateVeh..Language["Email_2"]..modelName..Language["Email_3"]..expire,
            image = '/public/html/static/img/icons/app/mail.png',
            button = {
              buttonEvent = "",
              buttonData = data,
              buttonname = "SetLocation"
            }
         })
    elseif Config.Utility.Phone == "notify" then
        Notify("Your vehicle: "..plateVeh.." has been register with insurance.", "success", 5000)
    end
end

function RepairVehicle()
    local playerPed = PlayerPedId()
    local veh = GetVehiclePedIsIn(playerPed, false)
    local plate = Config.Utility.CustomPlate and string.gsub(GetVehicleNumberPlateText(veh),' ','') or GetVehicleNumberPlateText(veh)

    QBCore.Functions.TriggerCallback('m-Insurance:Server:haveInsurance', function(hasInsurance)
        if not hasInsurance then
            Notify(Language["NoInsurance"], "error", 5000)
        else
            -- Has insurance
            QBCore.Functions.TriggerCallback('m-Insurance:Server:HaveMoneyRepair', function(hasMoney)
                if not hasMoney then
                    Notify(Language["NoMoney"], "error", 5000)
                else
                    if veh then
                        QBCore.Functions.Progressbar("RepairVehicle", Language["Repairing"], 5000, false, true, {
                            disableMovement = true, disableCarMovement = true, disableMouse = false, disableCombat = true
                        }, {}, {}, {}, function()
                            FreezeEntityPosition(veh, true)
                            SetVehicleFixed(veh)
                            SetVehicleEngineHealth(veh, 1000.0)
                            SetVehicleBodyHealth(veh, 1000.0)
                            SetVehiclePetrolTankHealth(veh, 1000.0)
                            SetVehicleDirtLevel(veh, 0)
                            SetVehicleOnGroundProperly(veh)
                            FreezeEntityPosition(veh, false)
                            if Config.Utility.Garages == "qs" then
                                exports['qs-advancedgarages']:RepairSpecificVehicle(veh)
                            end
                            Notify(Language["Repaired"], "success", 5000)
                        end)
                    end
                end
            end)
        end
    end, plate)
end
```

Getting a return error of Nill Value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7ckV.png)

adding an insurance script to fiveM for vehicles and keep getting this error in return. not sure why the script isnt working.
ive updated the main config and correct one error with the job listings.
i can seem to locate where the returen Value Nill error is originating from.
all i know right now is that its coming from thi string of code.

Comment: `:1` indicates the error is occurring on the very first line of the script. In `Config.Utility.CoreName`, `Config` resolves to a *nil* value, as the error says: you are trying to index a *nil* value with the field `'Utility'`. Either the variable was never defined, or somewhere it has been explicitly set to *nil* (i.e., `Config = nil`). I am not familiar with FiveM - is `Config` normally defined by the host environment? (Why do you expect it to *not* be *nil*?)